# Run cmd commands in JScript

Tags: jscript

I have a cmd command which I need to execute in JScript. So, I'm trying the next sequence of code:

```
var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
sevenZip = "C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe";
WshShell.Run("cmd.exe /c '"+sevenZip+" e "+File+" -p"+Pass+"'");
```

But when I launch the script, the cmd window opens, then closes, but the command doesn't seem to be executed. What am I doing Wrong?

Comment: Change `/c` to `/k` to keep the cmd window open afterward, so you can see any error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using `Shell.Aplication` instead. Here's the code how it should look like :

```
var objShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
sevenZip = "C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe";
executableCommand = "x " + zipFile + " -p" + zipPass + " -o" + Temp;
objShell.ShellExecute("7z.exe", executableCommand, sevenZip , "open", 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, you made my day

Answer (score 0):

chcp 1251,866 - change it to your regional parameters

```
var htmlfile=new ActiveXObject('htmlfile').parentWindow;
var alert=function(s){htmlfile.alert(s)};
var echoIt='Hi'
//...solve the problem of doubling percentages in variables during transmission by introducing the parameter /v!
var cmdCode=[
    'for /F "tokens=1-6 delims=:., " %A In ("!date! !time!") Do (Echo %A.%B.%C %D:%E:%F)',
    'set var='+echoIt,
    'echo %var%',
    'echo !var!'
];//'setlocal disableDelayedExpansion' parameter is useless becose /v
var std, arr=[];
var WshRunning=0,WshFinished=1,WshFailed=2;var i=0;tryCount=0,output=[],errors=[];  
with (new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell')) {
    std=Exec("cmd /v /q /k echo off"); //Turning on the /v option last, switches the output here in its entirety, including C:\...\notepad>
    std.StdIn.WriteLine("chcp 1251>nul");
    for(var i=0;i<cmdCode.length;i++) {
        std.StdIn.WriteLine(cmdCode[i]);
    };
    std.StdIn.WriteLine("chcp 866>nul");
    std.StdIn.WriteLine("exit");
    do{
        if (std.Status==WshFailed){
            errors.push('Error in string '+i+' :\n   '+std.StdErr.ReadLine());
            tryCount++
        }
        else if(std.Status==WshRunning){
            output.push(std.StdOut.ReadLine());
            tryCount=0;
            WScript.Echo('Running ...')
        }
        else if(std.Status==WshFinished){
            var last=std.StdOut.ReadLine();
            if(last.length>0){output.push(last)};last=undefined;
            tryCount=21;
            WScript.Echo('Finished ...')
        }i++;
    }while(tryCount<21);    
}
WScript.Echo('')
if (output.length>0){for(var i=0;i<output.length;i++) {WScript.Echo(output[i])}}
if (errors.length>0){alert(errors)}
var x=WScript.StdIn.ReadLine();
```

or

```
var std, arr = [];
var oWsh = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
with (new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell')) {
    std = Exec("cmd /q /k chcp 1251>nul");
    with (std.StdIn){
        WriteLine("dir "+ oWsh.SpecialFolders("Desktop"));
        WriteLine("exit");
    }
    arr = std.StdOut.ReadAll().split('\n'); //чтение данных
}
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    WScript.echo(i+' '+arr[i]);
}   
var x = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine();
```